# Visual Paradigm Class Diagram Drawing

Tags: uml, class-diagram, visual-paradigm

I need to create a Class Diagram with some *Model Packages*. I have to use Visual Paradigm as modeling editor. The target I'm looking for is a diagram like this one:

[image]

My problem is the following: how to create a Class like the classes in this picture?

I'm trying with the default Class command:

[image]

but it's not what I'm looking for. The class name must be centered and without the separation line. How can I do this?

I have also tried with Rectangles and Text Boxes overlapped, but in this case I'm not able to draw associations between the classes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hide the class attributes and methods.

Comment: please mark the question as answered even though it was given with a comment

Comment: @observer Sorry, but I don't know how to do it. I don't see any "accept answer" button. Can you help me?

Comment: According to meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/82099/answering-comment-answered-questions there is several options for comments that actually give an answer. Pick your favorite :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is very simple: you have to hide all the class attributes and methods (thank you, clapas!)